# Postman: SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse

Tags: json, rest, next.js, syntax-error

I am a beginner at web development and I am trying to use Postman to send a POST request to one of my application's APIs.
I am using the Next.JS framework to build my website.

Here is my API:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"

export default async (
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse,
) => {

    const userData = JSON.parse(req.body)
    res.status(200).json(userData)
}
```

I simplified my API until I caught the error, and I believe that it is related to the `JSON.parse(req.body)` line.

[This is a print of the data that I used to test the API on Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFHqK.png)

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (\u003canonymous\u003e)
at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/login.ts:9:27)
```

Previously, I used this API to authenticate users, and everything worked fine, except when I tried to insert data into the body of a Postman POST request.

Can someone help me? I have no idea what to do.

Comment: You're sending the POST data in `multipart/form-data` format, you can't simply handle it with `JSON.parse`. Try sending the body as a JSON string instead.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue adding FormData via Router Handler (App Router)

If you are having simliar issue be aware with a NextRequest object you canl call `req.formData()` to return form data, no need parsing.

Also sending a `multipart/form-data` header is not needed using this method.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I don't understand why they don't talk about this in nextjs documentation, if they do I totally missed it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deserialize the body from a POST request, you also have to send a request where the body contains any data because otherwise, `req.body` will be `null` and that is not valid json.